# export default is not getting transpile while traspiling code using babel and webpack

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs, transpiler

I am building an application in which i m transpiling my es6 code to es5 to make it ready for browser. I am using "export default" for exporting any data/class for accessible in other files. But this "export default" is not working well. How can i resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you define _"not working well"_?

Answer (score 0):

maybe this link can help your problem to export default in es5 http://es6-features.org/#DefaultWildcard

Comment: Link answers are okay as long as you explain in the answer too.